# Find matrix of $f$ in the canonical basis such that $ \ker f =\bigl\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3/x+y=0 \bigl\}$ and $f \circ f =2f$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be endomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $ \ker f =\bigl\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3/x+y=0 \bigl\}$ ,There exists an $k \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $f(0,1,0)=k(0,1,0)$ and $f \circ f =2f$
find matrix of $f$ in the canonical basis.
**My attempts**:
we have that $ \ker f =\bigl\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3/x+y=0\bigl\}$  then $\ker f= \text{span} \bigl\{[-1,1,0]^\dagger\bigl\}$  and we have $f(0,1,0)=k(0,1,0)$ so $f(e_2)=ke_2$.
what we can conclude from $f \circ f =2f$.

Comment: The kernel is two dimensional. You're missing a vector in it!

Comment: @Pedro yes the vector$ (0,0,1)$

Comment: The answer to your question is that you can conclude what the value of $k$ is. Very obviously, too. You do know what $f\circ f$ means, don't you?

Comment: @PaulSinclair $k=0$ or $k=2$

Comment: Since you know the kernel of $f$, one of those can be eliminated. Now that you know what $k$ is, note that you know the value of $f$ for $(0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ and $(-1,1,0)$. What can you figure out from that?